# Windows Batch file - matching files that contain a pattern but DO NOT end with that same pattern

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm trying to match files in a batch file, that contain the pattern `.log.` in the name but do not end in `.log` .

I have tried to match files with the following command:
`dir *.log.*`

This matches all that contains `.log` even if it is at the end. I've also tried with the following pattern:
`*\.log\.*` , but the compiler looks for a path, which is not intended.

I would appreciate some help, thank you in advance!

Comment: This works: `dir /B *.log.* | findstr "\.log\..*"`

Comment: @Aacini, you should add the `/I` option to `findstr`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine a `FOR` loop with an `IF` statement

read `HELP FOR` and `HELP IF`

and then try something like this in the command prompt

```
@for %a in (*.log.*) do @if /i not "%~xa"==".log" @echo %a
```

and then add it to your batch file

```
for %%a in (*.log.*) do (
  if /i not "%%~xa"==".log" (
    echo %%a
  )
)
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! I had to append each name to a variable since i was trying to zip all files using tar.exe and could only use verbose or specify each name, but at the end of the day, the answer to the question is here.